# Переосмысление указателей

Tags: c++

Я часто пишу разную ерунду для эксперимента (чтоб получше понять что  к чему). Вот одна из них:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using  std::string;
struct Test {
    char* s;
    Test(const string str)
        : s(new char[strlen(str.c_str()) + 1])
    { strcpy(s, str.c_str()); }
};
int main()
{      
    const string ms = "string"; 
    Test t(ms);  
    char* p = t.s; 
    //преобразование указателья на содержащий указатель на строку "string"?
    char *pt = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&t);     
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ms.size(); ++i) {
        *pt = 'x' + i;   // UB?
        std::cout << t.s << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
 /*результат:
    string
    tring
    ring
    ing
    ng
    g*/
```

Хотелось бы получше понять что тут происходит.  Хотелось бы услышать ответ подробнее(насколько это возможно).
Извеняюсь: добавлю к вопросу
почему  указатели p и  pt  указывают на разную сущность?

Comment: В p вы копируете указатель на строку. А pt указывает на начало структуры, где лежит указатель, т.е. адрес строки, а не сама строка. получается, что pt это указатель на указатель на строку

Comment: @Mike, я тоже так представлял,  но в таком случаи *pt == p. Но это не так...

Comment: `*pt` это значение одного байта, по адресу, содержащемуся в pt. (т.к. тип char), а `p` это сам указатель, т.е. четырехбайтовое (или 8) значение находящееся по тому же адресу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас есть структура `Test`, хранящая в себе указатель `s` типа `char *`. В строке

```
Test t(ms);
```

конструируется объект `t` типа `Test`. Судя по конструктору, указатель `t.s` инициализируется валидным значением. Теперь `t.s` указывает на первый элемент массива `char`'ов, который оканчивается нулевым символом, т.е. `t.s` указывает на первый символ некоторой строки.

Затем, вы получаете адрес объекта `t` и преобразуете его к указателю на `char`:

```
char *pt = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&t);
```

Таким образом, `pt` хранит адрес первого байта объекта `t`, **но не строки**, на которую указывает указатель `t.s`!.

Следующим шагом, вы начинаете изменять объект `t` через **указатель на его первый байт**:

```
*pt = 'x' + i;
```

Повторюсь ещё раз: вы изменяете не строку, адрес первого символа которой хранится в указателе `t.s`, который в свою очередь является подобъектом `t`, вы изменяете непосредственно первый байт объекта `t`.

Не то что бы так делать нельзя, но в данном конкретном случае, результат может быть непредсказуемым. Немного модифицируем тело функции `main`, чтобы посмотреть как изменяется `t.s` после модификации первого байта объекта `t`:

```
const string ms = "st"; 
Test t(ms);  
char* p = t.s; 
char *pt = reinterpret_cast<char*>(&t);     

//Выводим адреса символов строки, на которую указывает  t.s
for (size_t i = 0; i < ms.size(); ++i)
    cout << "original = " << uintptr_t(t.s + i) << endl;

for (size_t i = 0; i < ms.size(); ++i) {
    *pt = 'x' + i;   // UB?

    //Выводим модифицированный t.s
    cout << "modified = " << uintptr_t(t.s) << endl;
    //std::cout << t.s << endl;
}
```

Один из возможных выводов программы [выглядит так](https://ideone.com/ROI46s):

```
original = 94862834732064  
original = 94862834732065  
modified = 94862834732152  
modified = 94862834732153
```

Видно, что `t.s` после модификации указывает за пределы строки, на которую он указывал изначально. `t.s` — невалидный указатель, попытка его разыменования приводит к неопределённому поведению.

Если очень сильно повезёт, то первый байт объекта `t` будет равен значению символа `'x'` и программа отработает именно так как в вашем вопросе, но это просто совпадение.

Answer (score 2):

`*pt = 'x' + i;` будет изменять первый октет указателя `t.s` делая его невалидным. Последующие попытки разыменовать его приводят к неопределенному поведению.

Comment: Ваш ответ  тоже можно было принять как лучший